# how to make link button in html with out using server tag in asp.net page

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Hi all I have got menu options like HOWTOBUY,CONTACT US, CAREERS AND LOGOUT....My problem is I need to use last menu option(LOGOUT)as linkbutton  so that I need to write some code when that button(link) is clicked... I need to put these menu options in header page and I am using master page as well..

UseCase; If I made that button as a asp.net linkbutton I need to use  FORM tag in content page in form but I need to put these menu link options in header part of the page

how can I overcome this problem  not using asp.net buttons and need to call server side function with out using **runat=Server** Tag...

would you please any one help on this that will be very greatful to me ...

many thanks in advance....

Comment: Could you add some example code of your page structure?

Comment: I solved this problem myself....

Comment: In that case add an answer explaining your solution to the question.